# Different result for request and copied curl (PHP)

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to read out a website like any user would see it. 
When I visit the website normally and send a request via the browser the response is as an html page with certain results based on userinput. 
But when i copy the request my browser sends as curl (chrome and ff feature) and send the request as curl in PHP, the result is different. There are no results and a PHP error is displayed:
 array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array in /data/www/private/libvd2/htmlform.php

To me it looks like the server cant read the array curl sends, although this should be the same as the array my browser sends. 
Below and image of the send headers and the curl request in php.

Can someone figure out what is going wrong?

[image: send headers]

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://URL/publiek/tickets.php?PRESET%5BTickets%5D%5Bnaam%5D%5B%5D=BOM&PRESET%5BTickets%5D%5Bdag%5D%5B%5D=2018-04-03");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip, deflate');

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
$headers[] = "Accept-Language: nl,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3";
$headers[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
//$headers[] = "Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.1714037908.1502746144; publiek=atu07sbfc09qtm8nvpqcbkunna";
$headers[] = "Host: publiek.usc.ru.nl";
$headers[] = "Referer: https://URL/publiek/tickets.php?PRESET%5BTickets%5D%5Bnaam%5D%5B%5D=BOM";
$headers[] = "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1";
$headers[] = "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.13; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this->cookie);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
} else {
    print_r($result);
}
curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: The website https://publiek.usc.ru.nl needs login to access the url https://publiek.usc.ru.nl/publiek/tickets.php?PRESET%5BTickets%5D%5Bnaam%5D%5B%5D=BOM&PRESET%5BTickets%5D%5Bdag%5D%5B%5D=2018-04-03.
I htink you are just accessing the site without logging into it. pardon me if I am wrong.

Comment: Logging in works fine, I can access other pages with no problems

Comment: I solved it. The website im accessing needs to initialize the page first and probably set some cookies (dont ask me why, its ridiculous). So when I send a request without params first and my request above after that, it works fine.